# Set "run as administrator" on exe file on Windows OS with Ansible script

Tags: ansible

I would like to set "Run as Administrator" flag on a .exe file with an Ansible script.
I looked at the Ansible documentation, but it's only giving the "become" settings... which is not what I need basically.

Please let me know if you need more details, thanks for all your helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to always run program as administrator, go to Properties of your .exe file, next go to Compatibility tab and mark "Run this program as administrator"

I hope i help...

Comment: I know manually how to do it, I want it to do on the Ansible script way.